# Get specific value from .txt file using identifier VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I try to create a config file using .txt files, here I find it difficult to read the contents of the format.. already from yesterday I searched on google , but no similar case like me or maybe I missed it..

contents of .txt I have is as follows :

> Cek Server IP = 192.168.10.1
>
> Server IP = 192.168.10.1
>
> Cek My Website = www.google.com
>
> My Website = www.anothersite.com

this is my code :

```
WebControl.Source = New Uri("about:blank")
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("XXX") Then
    WebControl.Source = New Uri("ZZZ")
Else
    MsgBox("CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

what i want is how to get value "192.168.10.1" From "Cek Server IP" then send to "XXX" and Get Value "192.168.10.1" from "Server IP" then send to "ZZZ"

How can i do that?

Sory for my bad english. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I would suggest you use the .config file or a .xml file format. You wouldn't need to parse the file yourself.

Comment: ...or use My.Settings is there is just the one set of values, if there are several use a collection class and serialize it

Comment: for now it is only that, but maybe someday there is the addition of another.. I had wanted to use .config files or .xml format , but in fact I have never worked with .xml , .config or My.Setting files .. and I do not know where to start. this is something new for me. and what should I do with my question ? what should I delete it ?

Comment: I can give you a solution using .txt file though I suggest using .xml or .config file. Do you want it? By the way, I am not very conversant in VB.NET so will it work if my code is in C#? Can you convert it?

Comment: of course, why not .. maybe I could try to apply in VB.net and I know a site that can convert code C# to VB.net.

Comment: @CrazyThink - Okay my answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to read the values from your .txt file by giving its key. For that, you will have to write a function first that gets a key as a parameter and return the value:

```
    private String GetValue(String key)
    {
        Boolean isValueFound = false;
        String line = null;

        //Open your file
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("YourFile.txt"))
        {
            //Read it line-by-line
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //When the required line is found, set the flag and come out of the loop
                if (line.Trim().StartsWith(key))
                {
                    isValueFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isValueFound)
        {
            //Split the line by using = as separator. So at index 0, you have the key and at index 1 you have the value
            String[] strArray = line.Split('=');
            //Trim the value before returning to get rid of extra spaces
            return strArray[1].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            //if value is not found, return null
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call the above function like this:

```
    //This line will give you 192.168.10.1
    String result = this.GetValue("Cek Server IP");

    //This line will return www.google.com
    result = this.GetValue("Cek My Website");
```

Answer (score 0):

For file I/O, the [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has some useful methods, and for text files, the [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is probably what you want.  You can then use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for the `=` character, and [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to separate the lines into key and value parts.

You could wrap this up into a class to read and parse your configuration file, and give you access to the specific values, e.g. (you will probably need some `Import`s and `Option Infer On`):

```
Public Class SettingsFile

    Private ReadOnly _settings As IDictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub New(settings As IDictionary(Of String, String))
        _settings = settings
    End Sub

    Public Default ReadOnly Property Item(name As String) As String
        Get
            Dim value As String = Nothing
            _settings.TryGetValue(name, value)
            Return value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function Load(fileName As String) As SettingsFile
        Dim settings = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        For Each line In File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(Function(x) x.Contains("="))
            Dim parts = line.Split("="c)
            If parts.Count = 2 Then
                settings(parts(0).Trim()) = parts(1).Trim()
            End If
        Next
        Return New SettingsFile(settings)
    End Function

End Class
```

You could then use this class in your code, e.g.:

```
Dim s = SettingsFile.Load("C:\Path\To\Settings.txt")
Dim s1 = s("Cek Server IP")  ' 192.168.10.1
Dim s2 = s("Cek My Website") ' www.google.com
Dim s3 = s("Bad Key")        ' Nothing
```

Comment: you're late .. but thank you , I 've found the solution .. I also will try your code also to compare its simplicity .